# How can Go hold huge number with untyped const in background?

Tags: go

When I read about [Constants in Go](https://blog.golang.org/constants#Float)
I found this:

```golang
const Huge = 1e1000
fmt.Println(Huge / 1e999)
```

prints 10

what making me confused is how does Go holds this huge value background?
string?

Comment: Go doesn't "hold" constants anywhere. It substitutes them at compile time.

Comment: @Flimzy if doesn't hold, how can Go calculate 1e1000 / 1e999

Comment: There's nothing to hold there. It divides the two numbers, and replaces "10" in the compiled output. The only thing "held" is `10`, if you consider "writing to the compiled output file" to be holding.

Comment: @Flimzy: I think the OP is asking how the Go compiler stores the number internally for the duration of the compilation. (Of course the answer to this is "however it likes" :-) )

Comment: @torek yes! you exactly know what i mean, thank you so much. but what does "however it likes" mean?

Comment: The [language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec) says what *must* happen. It is up to the compiler writer to come up with a method by which what *must* happen, actually *does* happen. As long as the compiler-writer's code meets the spec, it suffices. The spec in this case says that `1e1000` should work and represent 1 times ten to the 1000 as an abstract number. See aslo the "implementation restriction" section in https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants: it suffices for the compiler to hold all constants internally as a 256 bit mantissa with a signed, 16 bit exponent.

Comment: Note that the implementation restriction requires the compiler-writer to produce an error if the abstract number exceeds 256 bits when converted to integer—which means 256 bits of mantissa suffices regardless of exponent—and to round to nearest if the abstract number loses precision when converted to floating-point. However, if you're a compiler author and can come up with a better/faster/whatever way to meet the specification, that's fine too.

Comment: @torek i get it. thank u so much !

Answer (score -4):

Values are encoded in floating point. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) how 64 bit floating point values are encoded.

Floating points have 11 bits to encode the exponent. Combined with the sign bit, this is +/- 1024. No problem to encode such a big value without loss of precision.

Comment: There are no floating point values in the example, only untyped constants. No type is assigned until `fmt.Println()` is evaluated, at which point the constant has already been converted to `10`.